# "By equating to (something)": Implicit object or typo or bad grammar?

Tags: grammar, objects, elision

In p.251, "*Introduction to statistics and probability for engineers and scientists*, Sheldon M.Ross, 6th edition", I found this sentence:

> By equating to zero, we obtain that the *maximum likelihood estimate* **lambda_hat** equals (some value).

For which the author means: To equate some equation (in previous page of the book) that contains **lambda_hat** (the so-called *maximum likelihood estimate*) to zero to solve for **lambda_hat**.

It's not clear to me that this is a case of bad grammar, a typo or a usage of the implicit object or something I'm being unaware of?

Also I couldn't find in any popular online dictionary such phrase "By equating to (something)".

Comment: equate to something: to be the same in amount, number, or size:
*The price of such goods in those days equates to about $50 at current prices.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/equate-to

Comment: The first three "popular dictionaries online" that come up on Google do mention it...

Comment: Note that you can equate an *expression* or a *variable* to zero, not an equation. This sort of wording is more common in Maths lectures than books or papers, which are more formal .

Comment: @user66974 That's "Something equates to something else", here is "By equating to something else". One may ask equating (what?) to something else.

Comment: "By setting to zero" seems more usual, in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be

- finding where the derivative is zero
- by taking an expression for the derivative,
- *equating the expression to zero* (which means forming an equation by sticking "=0" on the end; ELU has a bad zero)
- and solving the resulting equation.

Comment: Yes, normal math talk after referring to the expression: "By equating to 0, ..."